# # of Bytes at Serial Port Input Buffer

Tags: c, linux, serial-port

New to C programming here so bear with me..  I wrote a program to write/read data to and from the serial port.  Everything appears to be working except when I try to read the number of bytes available at the port that have been received.  Here's my code (see the read_port function):

```
#include <stdio.h>       /* Standard input/output definitions */
#include <string.h>      /* String function definitions */
#include <unistd.h>      /* UNIX standard function definitions */
#include <fcntl.h>       /* File control definitions */
#include <errno.h>       /* Error number definitions */
#include <termios.h>     /* POSIX terminal control definitions */
#include <sys/ioctl.h>   /* Serial Port IO Controls */

int fd; /* File descriptor for the port */
struct termios options_original;  /* Original Serial Port Options */

int main()
{
  fd = open_port();
  flush_port();
  write_port();
  printf("FIONBIO value %d\n", FIONBIO);
  usleep(2);
  printf("FIONREAD value %d\n", FIONREAD);
  read_port();
  close_port();
}

/*
 * open_port() - Open serial port 1.
 *
 * Returns the file descriptor on success or -1 on error
 */
int open_port(void)
{
  struct termios options;

  fd = open("/dev/ttyUSB0", O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_NDELAY | O_NONBLOCK);
  if (fd != -1)
  {
    printf("Serial Port Open\n");
    fcntl(fd, F_SETFL, 0);
    tcgetattr(fd, &options_original);
    tcgetattr(fd, &options);
    cfsetispeed(&options, B115200);
    cfsetospeed(&options, B115200);
    options.c_cflag |= (CLOCAL | CREAD); /* Enable the receiver and set local mode */
    options.c_lflag &= ~(ICANON | ECHO | ECHOE | ISIG);  /* Raw Input Mode */
    tcsetattr(fd, TCSANOW, &options);    /* Set the new options for the port */
  }
  else
  {
    /* Could not open the port */
    perror("open_port: Unable to open /dev/ttyUSB0 - ");
  }

  return (fd);
}

int close_port(void)
{
  tcsetattr(fd, TCSANOW, &options_original);
  printf("Serial Port Closed\n");
  close(fd);
}

int flush_port(void)
{
  usleep(2); // required to make flush work, for some reason
  printf("Flushing IO Buffers\n");
  tcflush(fd, TCIOFLUSH);
}

int write_port(void)
{
  int n = write(fd, "DSC", 3);
  if (n < 0)
    fputs("write() of 1 byte failed!\n", stderr);
  else
    printf("Wrote %0d bytes to serial port\n", n);
}

int read_port(void)
{
  int  chars_read = 3;
  int  bytes;
  char read_buffer[3] = {0};
  int  i;

  fcntl(fd, F_SETFL, 0);
  ioctl(fd, FIONBIO, &bytes);
  printf("Number of bytes = %d\n", bytes);
  int n = read(fd, read_buffer, chars_read);
  printf("Character at Port: %s\n", read_buffer);
  printf("Number of chars read = %0d\n", n);
}
```

Here's the output:

```
Serial Port Open
Flushing IO Buffers
Wrote 3 bytes to serial port
FIONBIO value 21537
FIONREAD value 21531
Number of bytes = 0
Character at Port: DSC
Number of chars read = 3
Serial Port Closed
```

For some reason 'Number of bytes' always equals 0.  I have no idea why.  Is there something wrong with doing this?

```
  int  bytes;
  ioctl(fd, FIONBIO, &bytes);
  printf("Number of bytes = %d\n", bytes);
```

It's pretty much verbatim from this site:
http://www.cmrr.umn.edu/~strupp/serial.html#config

Am I missing or not understanding something?

BTW I'm just doing a simple loopback test here.

Comment: Upvote simply for knowing the proper formatting difference between a C keyword (i.e. **if**) and a procedure/function name.  But you should test the return codes of **tc[gs]etattr()**, **ioctl()** and all other syscalls.

Answer (score 1):

`ioctl(fd, FIONBIO, ...)` sets a file descriptor (e.g. a socket) into blocking or
non-blocking mode. What you probably meant is

```
ioctl(fd, FIONREAD, &bytes);
```

to get the number of bytes available in the input buffer (i.e. the number of bytes
that can be read without blocking.)

Comment: I just switch it and tested it with no luck.  I originally used FIONREAD but that didn't work (I was looking at some other code I found online and tried FIONBIO, with no luck). So neither one seem to work for me. Could it be something with my #include <sys/ioctl.h>?

Comment: I don't think so. If FIONREAD does not work then I have no idea.

Comment: I'll play around with this again tonight and see if I can come up with anything.  Thanks again for the help, I appreciate it.